# SQLAlchemy require primary key to be generated by program

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When defining a table, you define one column as `primary_key=True`. As shown in the [tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#create-an-instance-of-the-mapped-class), SQLAlchemy will automatically create an ID for an item, even when it is not supplied by the user. The `primary_key=True` also automatically sets `nullable=False`.

Is there a way that I can set up the Primary Key so that it is required, but is not filled by SQLAlchemy? I want my program to *have* to supply a primary key for each row.

Something like:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autogenerate=False)
    name = Column(String)
    nickname = Column(String)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [autoincrement](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html?highlight=autoincrement#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement) attribute to `False` to get this effect*.  This code

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa


meta = sa.MetaData()
tbl = sa.Table('test20210102a', meta,
               sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
               sa.Column('name', sa.String(8)))

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:///test', echo=True)

meta.drop_all(bind=engine)
meta.create_all(bind=engine)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(tbl.insert({'name': 'foo'}))
engine.dispose()
```

emits this warning when the table is created

> SAWarning: Column 'test20210102a.id' is marked as a member of the primary key for table 'test20210102a', but has no Python-side or server-side default generator indicated, nor does it indicate 'autoincrement=True' or 'nullable=True', and no explicit value is passed.  Primary key columns typically may not store NULL.

and produces this error

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, foo).

---

* The above code should work for most RDBMS.  Sqlite has different autoincrement semantics, as described in the [dialect information](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlite-auto-incrementing-behavior), but you can get similar behaviour by using a different integer type for the id column:

```py
sa.Column('id', sa.SmallInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
```